# How to deal in Highcharts with special characters from CSV file?

Tags: csv, highcharts, special-characters

I have a CSV file with german characters ("ä", "ü") which are read by Highcharts. But those special characters don't get displayed properly. I tried to change the text encoding, UTF8, LATIN1, ..., but in vain.

Anybody has a tip? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you recreate your example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Recreate is not possible as it reads the CSV. But here is link to  [the graph](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/megatrends/data/soil_use.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least part of the solution was to switch in the CSV Editor the encodings a couple of times and then at the end back to UTF8. And then it worked.

However, the special characters in the title of the axis appear only ok when using ISO Latin 1. Otherwise, still awkward characters.

Answer (score 1):

You should have utf-8 encoding in all files.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXnhL/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['ä', 'ä']
    },        
    series: [{
        data: [29, 71]        
    }]
});
```

Works well.

Comment: It's not about the special characters per se. But as you can see from the above example ("link to the graph"), it does not display them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having difficulties to print special characters in the Highcharts. This is how i resolve the issue. Set 'useHTML' to true to print the special characters in the title. I thought it may be helpful to someone who come to this page.
  title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: 'Monthly – Temperature'
        },